# Test if a vector belongs to a subspace

Tags: calculus, vectors

I have to test if vector (U5) belongs to subspace R. U5=(1,6,-7,8) and R=(a+b,-2a,a-b,2b). Therefore R is made up by two vectors(R1+R2). Vector R1=a(1,-2,1,0) and vector R2=b(1,0,-1,2).

So far i've gaussed them and found that the system is inconsistend and therefore they are lineary independent and u5 does not belong to R. Is this right?

[image]

---

Okay so i just split the R into two vectors. And from there i Gauss it down so i get -3 and 4. I think i understand that part :) The end of your answer confuses me though. Do i need to transpose the unknown x? or what do you mean by the last sentence x=(a,b)^T?

Comment: What is R? Is it the span of $(a+b,-2a,a-b,2b)$ for certain $b$ and $a$, or is it the set $\{(a+b,−2a,a−b,2b)∣a,b∈\mathbb{R}\}$?

Comment: Maybe good to clarify that the vectors spanning the subspace for paramters in this case are $a: (1,-2,1,0)$ and for $b: (1,0,-1,2)$. If you look closely those values are the coefficients for $a$ and $b$ respectively in the $R=$ expression.

Comment: $R$ has infinite many vectors, but is the linear span of your vectors $R_1$ and $R_2$, thus the set of all their real linear combinations.

Comment: ived edited it now - hope the meaning is clear.

Comment: Welcome to the site by the way. You are encouraged to learn MathJax which benefits from learning the LaTeX typesetting language to typeset formula and equations.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what  your image means. But, all you have to show is that there exists $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ (I suppose that you are talking about a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$) such that:

$$\begin{cases}
a+b=1\\
-2a=6\\
a-b=-7\\
2b=8
\end{cases}
$$
and the solution is simple: $a=-3$ and $b=4$.

Comment: Okay so i just split the R into two vectors. And from there i Gauss it down so i get -3 and 4. I think i understand that part :) The end of your answer confuses me though. Do i need to transpose the unknown x? or what do you mean by the last sentence x=(a,b)^T?

Answer (score 1):

Your $R$ is the set
$$
R = \{ (a+b, -2a, a-b, 2b) \mid a, b \in \mathbb{R} \}
$$
the task is to determine, if there are real $a$ and $b$ which generate
$u_5 = (1,6,-7,8)$.

This leads to the system
$$
A x = y \iff \\
[A|y] \iff \\
\left[
\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
-2 & 0 & 6 \\
1 & -1 & -7 \\
0 & 2 & 8
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & -3 \\
1 & -1 & -7 \\
0 & 2 & 8
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rr|r}
0 & 1 & 4 \\
1 & 0 & -3 \\
0 & -1 & -4 \\
0 & 1 & 4
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & 0 & -3 \\
0 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$
in the unknown $x = (a, b)^\top$, with $A$ derived from the definition of $R$ and $y = u_5^\top$.

This system has the solution $x = (a, b)^\top = (-3, 4)^\top$. So $u_5 \in R$, because there is at least one solution $x$.